# Time reversal of Bloch waves in photonic crystals

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-spin, group-theory, time-reversal-symmetry

In solid-state physics, I understand that in the case of no spin, the time reversal operator $\hat{T}$ is equal to the complex conjugation operator $\hat{K}$ and in the case with spin, $\hat{T} = \hat{K}\sigma_y$ where $\sigma_y$ is the Pauli spin operator for $y$ (Dresselhaus, Group Theory, 2008; Ch. 16.2).

I see how for a scalar wavefunction $\psi(r,t)$, $\hat{T}\psi(r,t) = \psi(r, -t) = \psi^*(r,t)$.

My question is: in the case of Bloch wavefunctions in photonic crystals, why is $\hat{T} = \hat{K}$? I thought that photons have spin (from right and left-circularly polarized light) and thus, shouldn't $\hat{T} = \hat{K}\sigma_y$?